# Multi part nodes in `forest` tree

Tags: forest, tikz-node

In `forest` I like to use multi part nodes. In experiments I use the following simple MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, }

\begin{document}
\forestset{
 rect/.style = {rectangle split,
                rectangle split horizontal,
                rectangle split parts=4,
                draw},
          }% end of \forestset

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      rect,
      %
           }
[\nodepart{one} A
% \nodepart{two} B,
% \nodepart{three} C,
 \nodepart{four} $D$
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

If I use one more `\nodepart{...}`, for example `\nodepart{two} B`, compilation gives error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeyscurrentkey ->\nodepart 
                               {four} $D$
```

I wonder why it works with data for one or two node parts, but not with three or with all four. My searching for solution for multi part nodes was unsuccessful so far.

How to overcome this limitation?

Comment: The problem is the `,` after `B` and `C`. Without it, everything works.

Comment: Yes, and the solution is to enclose the node content in curly braces.

Comment: @Ignasi, huh, how stupid error! What a shame for me :-(. Thank you very much! Now I see, that left commas from some my another try (to write new command for nodes parts).

Comment: *Zarko asked a question*... but wait...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by comments.